# Custom distance metric for agglomerative clustering in Mathematica

Tags: string-manipulation, cluster-analysis

Is it possible to have a custom distance metric defined to determine the distance between two clusters in Agglomerative clustering in Mathematica?

I have a 3 dimension data with string values along all three dimensions.

I want to define my own way of measuring the distance between any two clusters (Strings here...)

Also, I want to stop the clustering when the distance between two clusters is greater than a particular threshold value "T".

Is this available in Mathematica?

Comment: By using the **HierarchicalClustering** package, you can define your own DistanceFunction between clusters. See for example http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/HierarchicalClustering/ref/Agglomerate.html (option DistanceFunction)

Comment: Thanks. Looked at it. It says that we can define our own DistanceFunction, but I am still wondering how do you instruct Mathematica to stop clustering if the distance is greater than "T" between two clusters for a "Complete" type of Linkage? Where do we specify this condition?

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial [tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters.html) has information on Distance functions (also for Strings, e.g. HammingDistance).

Comment: But there there is no reference nor examples on how to use a custom linkage function.

Answer (score 0):

Not as a built in function.  You will have to write your own.  Fortunately it's quite easy and the benefit is you now have a function that provides the custom distance important to your data.

```
euclidianDistance[{x_List, y_List, 
   z_List}, {xX_List, xY_List, 
  xZ_List}] := Block[{ed, dist, len, lenp},
    len = Length[xX];
    lenp = Length[x];
   If [len != lenp,
      Print["euclidianDistance:Standard and Sample sizes do not match"]];
    ed = Table[((x[[i]] - 
          xXL[[i]])^2 + (y[[i]] - 
          xY[[i]])^2 + (z[[i]] - 
          xZ[[i]])^2)^0.5, {i, 1, len}];
    dist = Chop[ed /. n_ /; n <= 0 -> 0.000000001]
    ]
```

Here's an easy example of Euclidian Distance.

Comment: Thanks Hall. But where can I mention the threshold value "T" that if the custom distance between two clusters is less than "T", then it should not proceed with clustering these two clusters in agglomerative clustering?

Comment: Also, can you just explain your last statement about CHOP please? Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar You will need to ad an If statement that provides the custom T factor your looking for.  Something Like:  If[T>1, do something, or else this];  The last statement, simply replaces approximate real numbers in the expr that are close to zero by the exact integer 0. and uses Rule replacement to make them a trivial non Zero value thats valuable if your functions do not handle zero values well.

Comment: Hall, thanks. Do you know where I should add such a statement? Here is my code:     myDistance[{x_List, y_List, z_List}, {xX_List, xY_List, xZ_List}] := Block[{ed, dist, len, lenp}, len = Length[xX]; lenp = Length[x]; If [len != lenp, Print["euclidianDistance:Standard and Sample sizes do not match"]]; ed = Table[((x[[i]] - xXL[[i]])^2 + (y[[i]] - xY[[i]])^2 + (z[[i]] - xZ[[i]])^2)^0.5, {i, 1, len}]; dist = Chop[ed /. n_ /; n <= 0 -> 0.000000001] ] dataF = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}; c = FindClusters[dataF, Method -> {"Agglomerate"}, 
  DistanceFunction -> myDistance]

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar The distance function must be run first, then use that variable to find clusters based on the If statement.